# Как подсчитать количество элементов в массиве ячейки MySQL?

Tags: mysql, массивы, сериализация

Пример запроса:

SELECT images FROM top WHERE id = 1,

Результат:

**images**

a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"url";s:10:"images.png";s:3:"tag";s:4:"plan";s:5:"**local**";s:69:"bf26b5eddd9df20905bdb4ed2ae02954/551cd996264554ef9d5fcc5753d31c08.png";s:5:"**local**";s:69:"bf26b5eddd9df20905bdb4ed2ae02954/551cd996264554ef9d5fcc5753d31c09.png";}}

Нужно подсчитать количество элементов "**local"**, т.е. в вышеприведенном примере их должно получится 2.

Comment: На Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Было бы не плохо понимать в каком формате представлен ответ на запрос. Если это строка, то можно попробовать функцию FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: Есть таблица с загруженными рисунками, в ней массив с локальными адресами загруженных картинок. Задача: 1) Проверить что эти скаченные файлы действительно являются картинками (getimagesize), если да - это картинки, то сохраняем пути в другую таблицу - actualimages. Но нужно понять, все ли картинки были обработаны (есть два столбца - источник и id внутри источника) getimagesize, вот для этого подсчитать общее количество таких local картинок и сравнить с таблицей "проверенных" картинок